# Why am I getting Error: Timeout in my Jasmine unit test of http interceptor?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-http-interceptors, stackblitz

I am struggling with unit testing my interceptor since yesterday noon. After following several tutorial and SO answers, I have a code that so far looks the best. BUT, because of some reason I am getting an error:

> Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by
> jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) Error: Timeout - Async function did
> not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
> at Jasmine

**EDIT**: I just added [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jasmine-in-angular-7c5hpm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsut%2Ferror.interceptor.spec.ts).

my test:

```
it('should display an error message if the request is unauthorized', (done) => {
    service.getGameState('1').subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        expect(data).toBeNull();
        expect(errorsMock.handleAuthError).toHaveBeenCalledWith('dupa');
        done();
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(error);
        done();
      }
    );

    const testRequest = httpMock.expectOne(
      'http://localhost:50962/api/game/join?id=1'
    );
    expect(testRequest.request.method).toBe('GET');
    testRequest.flush(null, {
      status: 401,
      statusText: 'Unauthorized request',
    });
  });
```

**NOTE**: `console.log` in the test are not called;

test preparation:

```
describe('ErrorInterceptor', () => {
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  let injector: TestBed;
  let service: HttpService;
  const errorsMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('ErrorService', [
    'handleBackendError',
    'handleAuthError',
    'handleBotError',
    'handleOtherError',
  ]);

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])],
      providers: [
        HttpService,
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: ErrorInterceptor,
          multi: true,
        },
        { provide: ErrorService, useValue: errorsMock },
      ],
    });

    injector = getTestBed();
    httpMock = injector.inject(HttpTestingController);
    service = TestBed.inject(HttpService);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpMock.verify();
  });

  it('Injector_ShouldBeCreated', () => {
    expect(injector).toBeTruthy();
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

**NOTE**: when using `.and.callThrough();` on `errorsMock` it throws an error:

> Cannot read property 'callThrough' of undefined

Why `errorsMock` is undefined?

Interceptor by himself:

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private error: ErrorService) {}

  public intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return new Observable((observer) => {
      next.handle(request).subscribe(
        (res: HttpResponse<any>) => {
          if (res instanceof HttpResponse) {
            observer.next(res);
          }
        },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          this.handleResponseError(err, request, next);
        }
      );
    });
  }

  private handleResponseError(
    error: HttpErrorResponse,
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): any {
    if (request.url.indexOf('refresh') !== -1) {
      return next.handle(request);
    }

    if (error.status === 0) {
      this.error.handleBackendError(error);
    } else if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403) {
      this.error.handleAuthError(error, next, request);
    } else if (error.status === 429) {
      this.error.handleBotError(error);
    } else {
      this.error.handleOtherError(error);
    }
  }
}
```

And `http.service` method:

```
public getGameState(id: string): Observable<any> {
    const url: string = environment.apiUrl + 'api/game/join?id=' + id;
    return this.http.get(url);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the time to read your interceptor and turns out your implemention is wrong, you should return an observeble:

```
 import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

  public intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
        catchError((err) => {
          this.handleResponseError(err, request, next);
          return throwError(err);
        })
      );
  }
```

Comment: For the first approach I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'callThrough' of undefined`, 2nd approach does not compile to me.

Comment: try the last one

Comment: I created `let mocks: any[] = [errorsMock];` and did like you said, with the same result: `Cannot read property 'callThrough' of undefined`. I wonder, what is the reason, why it thinks that `errorsMock` is `undefined`? I belive that is the key to solve it. Btw, I created **Stackblitz** example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/jasmine-in-angular-7c5hpm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsut%2Ferror.interceptor.spec.ts

Comment: looks good to me, I edited your stackblitz with my solution and it's working

Comment: I just edited my stackblitz and still not working, maybe I am doing something wrong? https://stackblitz.com/edit/jasmine-in-angular-7c5hpm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsut%2Ferror.interceptor.spec.ts

Comment: no need for `let mocks: any[] = [errorsMock];` just modify errorsMock direectly, please check my modified solution

Comment: But with your solution I am getting too `timeout` error: https://i.ibb.co/5MDbf9Z/testing.png

Comment: forget about what i said earlier, I edited my solution

Comment: Last review fixed the problem. Thank you!